# Next.js 13 scripts don't reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm new on Next.js 13 (i was using the 12) and with this new folder app the scripts don't reload when the page changes, just when you manually reload

I'm currently refactoring my javascript code, so i can use then on useEffect like it's a function, but i think there be a better resolution for this.

I'm searching but i can't find a way to load my script code as dinamically

Sorry for the bad english

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.